# How can i set the size and positions of my components in qml. so that it can support different devices

Tags: qt, qml

I'm developing a mobile app using App Studio for ArcGIS.

All my QML files has been set a fixed size and x,y axis according to my Xd files. But when I run it on my mobile and other mobiles - it does not support properly. I tried to find different solutions but I was not able to apply it on my page. Also, explored the scalability documentation of QML, but I was not able to understand it.

here is the sample code

```
App{
    id:app
    visible: true
    x: 0
    y: 0
    width: 375
    height: 812
    Page{
        anchors.fill: parent
    
        background: 
        Image {
            id: image
            x: 0
            y: 0
            width: 375
            height: 812
            fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
            source: "images/login_backgroud.png"
       }
    
       Button {
            id: button
            x: 52
            y: 674
            width: 284
            height: 40
            text: qsTr("Login")
            spacing: 0
            font.pointSize: 16
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchors and layouts instead of hard coding x and y. Set attribute for enabling high DPI scaling. Refer to this Qt documentation for supporting GUI scalability in different form factors, resolutions and DPI.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/scalability.html